# can I run multiple docker wordpress with external nginx and mysql

Tags: docker

I want to keep my external nginx without docker and my mysqld on the server without docker and simply set the wordpress instances to use one mysql db each on that mysqld.

I am wondering whether:
a) this is doable
b) I can do only a simple nginx proxy to the exposed wondpress instances with a unique ip such as blog1.my-server.com, blog2.my-server.com etc.

Anyone that has done this and can give me some pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to set up two different wp instances using a shared nginx proxy and two different mysql dbs? I'm a little confused.

Comment: I have a big server with nginx and mysql that I want to share among multiple dockerized worpress and other applications.  I want to set up a nginx virtualhost for each of the docker apps that are web based.

Comment: This could be complex. The MySQL part may be straightforward since the app server connects to it, but reverse proxy (nginx) has to know what to forward requests to. So it needs to be reconfigured and probably HUPped each time you create/destroy a container. Does that sound accurate?

Comment: How come?  I can bring up the container exposing whatever direct local port I wish, no?

Comment: Sure, but how is nginx going to know about those ports?